# Phaser Typescript function don't launch

Tags: html, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a  little HTM5 game using Phaser.io.

I have a small issue that I can't fix.

In my MainClass (the game), I just want to create a loop that will create a new object (a coin) and add it to a group.

But I don't know why, the little function I call never launch.

Here's my code :

```
  create() {

    //coins group
    this.coins = this.game.add.group;



    //set background
    this.game.stage.backgroundColor = "#00F6FA";
    //load the map
    this.map = this.game.add.tilemap('level', 195, 195, 2, 4);
    this.map.addTilesetImage('free-2d-game-tiles-post-pic-1', 'tiles');
    //load collision layer
    this.layer = this.map.createLayer('collision');
    //this.layer.debug = true;
    //make the layer collide  
    this.map.setCollisionBetween(8, 9, true, this.layer.index, true);
    //enable physics
    this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    //set the player
    this.player = new Player(this.game, 0, 0);


    this.game.time.events.repeat(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, 10, this.createCoin, this);
}
```

And just behind :

```
    createCoin(): void {
    /*

    generate a coin

    */
    console.log('test');

}
```

Pretty simple,but nothing never happen.

Do you see what I miss?

EDIT 1:

ok here's my code on Github :

https://github.com/c4n4r/coinFall/blob/master/JS/app.ts

I still don't know what's wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few thigs. First, we need whole code: how do you create the game and how do you apply create function to it?
Second, `this` is dynamiccaly binded. To bind it to your object, you may for example use fat arrow syntax: `createCoin = () => { ... }`.
Look at your `this` (`console.log(this)` in create method) - this is not what you expect it to be :)

Take a look at working example:

```
export default class SimpleGame {
    private game;

    constructor() {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { create: this.create });
    }

    //Used by Phaser to create real game - prepare it. Use fat arrow syntax here!
    create = () => {
        this.someInternalMethod();
    }

    //This is ok to make it as normal method, as only bounded this ( create) use it
    private someInternalMethod(){
        //Ok!
    }
}
```

Take a look at my source code (simple game in TS & Phaser) for more: https://github.com/Ami777/AmyInSpace

More about fat arrow in TS: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

More about this syntax in ES6: https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/ .

Regards, Jakub Król.

Comment: thank you for your time, here's my full code : https://github.com/c4n4r/coinFall/blob/master/JS/app.ts , maybe I have a lack of knowledge in TS but I still don't get it...

Comment: @HadrienDelphin Yes, your code with my comment is working. Just change `preload`, `render`, `create` and `update` definitions to `methodName => ()`. For example `preload => () {` etc and it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I would recommend using `Phaser.State`, that would make things a little easier I think. Then you can use the `extends` keyword in TypeScript, something like this:

```
class SimpleGame extends Phaser.State {

    // define your properties for SimpleGame
    coins: Phaser.Group;
    //game: Phaser.Game; // <- not needed! SimpleGame extends Phaser.State
    map: Phaser.Tilemap;
    // etc

    // define methods for SimpleGame
    create() {
        //.. create code here
        this.coins = this.add.group();

        // 'this' extends type Phaser.State, so notice you can use this.time:
        this.time.events.repeat(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, 10, this.createCoin, this);
    }

    update() {
        //.. update code here
    }

    createCoin() {
        //.. create a coin
        var newCoin = new Banana(this, this.world.randomX, 0)
        this.coins.add(newCoin)
    }
}
```